# Where is mesh debug to be found?

Tags: 3d-printing

I am working in blender 2.69 and have been following the Blender Tutorials DVD12 on Youtube --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaKYhO-XMFo
The video above refers to the "Mesh Debug" options in the properties pane. I know its only visible in edit mode but for some reason I can't see it on my version. i have also downloaded the latest version of Blender 2.76b and the mesh debug option is not visible there either. Any ideas how I can make this option show on my version?

Answer (score 4):

It's in the (by default included but disabled) 3d print toolbox addon, but it changed the name, now is called "mesh analysis" in the 3d view properties panel (open with <kbd>N</kbd>)

Comment: Uh-oh. Mesh Analysis has disappeared from the Properties Panel. How do I get it back? Meanwhile I'll continue looking through the Q and A's.

Comment: Doh. Never mind. I was in a hurry to leave for the day. Sorry for the newbie mistake.